# Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity() return string

Tags: php, zend-framework

why i cant get user as object ?

i use code to get user identity :

```
$identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()

echo $identity->usergroup
```

return Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

or

```
  $identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
        var_dump($identity);
```

give string 'test@g.pl' (length=9)

so how to get usergroup

login :

```
$request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost() and $loginForm->isValid($_POST)) {

            $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
                $db,
                'users',
                'useremail',
                'password'
            );

            $adapter->setIdentity($loginForm->getValue('useremail'));
            $adapter->setCredential($loginForm->getValue('password'));

            $auth   = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

            if ($result->isValid()) {

                $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Successful Login');
                $this->_redirect('/');
                return;
            }else{
                throw new Exception($result->getMessages()[0]);
            }
```

user model :

```
protected $_id;
protected $_useremail;
protected $_usergroup;
protected $_password;
protected $_password_salt;
protected $_realname;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use,

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);


if ($result->isValid()) {
            $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();
            $auth->getStorage()->write($user);
            return true;
        }
```

if `usergroup` is in the row that authenticates user,
you can use this,

```
 $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
 $usergroup = $auth->getIdentity()->usergroup;
```

or another field for that matter like,

```
$password = $auth->getIdentity()->password;
```

Or

```
$email = $auth->getIdentity()->email;
```

Use this  article by rob allen to understand more, [here](http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal behavior, in fact the getIdentity method returns the identity of the user, that is, the username.

Comment: so how to return user with usergroup

Comment: Fetch username from auth and then use it to retrieve the user object.

Comment: @matteo Tassinari sir,wouldn't it be the proper way as i described ?

Comment: I guess it would, I just wasn't able to write a long answer from my smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Auth session data

```
$identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
var_dump($identity)
```

`Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()` is return $username name only

Comment: @GrekHmhmm, the session stored data will return?, please try accordingly